# How to operate on spans of rows in a matrix?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a `[2001,2]` matrix of (x,y) values, but the number of rows could vary.

I would like to go through the entire matrix, and divide each of the y values by a certain number, depending on their x value.

For example, for x values from 600-700, I would like to divide the corresponding y value by 10. For x values from 700-800, I would like to divide the corresponding y value by 20.

My idea was a for loop that looped the entire matrix, and then nested "if" statements that said

```
if data[[n, 1]] < 700, data[[n, 2]] = data[[n, 2]]/10

if data[[n, 1]] >= 700 && data[[n, 1]] <800, data[[n, 2]] = data[[n, 2]]/20
```

However, I can't even figure out how to determine the number of rows in a matrix to ensure I loop the correct 2001 times (I want my code to work for any length).

`Dimensions[data]` doesn't help and `Length[Dimensions[data]]` doesn't do it either and neither does `Length[Dimensions[Transpose[data]]]`.

Comment: I don't see why `Dimensions` wouldn't work? What is your output thereof?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define your function that depends on $x$ as a `Piecewise`:

```
div[x_] := 
  Piecewise[{{1, x < 600}, {10, 700 > x >= 600}, {20, 
     800 > x >= 700}, {1, x >= 800}}];
```

Now apply it to your matrix, leaving $x$ the same and dividing $y$ by $div(x)$

```
a = RandomReal[{0, 1000}, {2001, 2}];
{#1, #2/div[#1]} & @@@ a
```

Do not use loops, more on that in [loop alternatives](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica).

Answer (score 5):

Take a matrix:

```
m = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {50, 2}];
```

`divlist` is the list in which you set the amount you want each row to be divided by.

```
divlist = Range[50]^2 + 4;
Thread[m/divlist]
```

> {{0.122485, 0.113589, 0.0614795, ..., -0.000421888, 0.000414203, -0.000404009, 
>     0.000252482},
>
> {0.181547, -0.0939199, -0.00331032, ..., -0.0000740111, -0.000279882, -0.000368139}}

Answer (score 1):

```
data = RandomInteger[{500., 800.}, {10, 2}]
```

> {{583, 614}, {518, 744}, {731, 732}, {783, 593}, {693, 742}, {658, 
>     601}, {552, 741}, {741, 569}, {522, 524}, {705, 533}}

```
Table[If[600 <= data[[i, 1]] < 700, data[[i, 2]] = data[[i, 2]]/10, 
   If[700 <= data[[i, 1]] < 800, data[[i, 2]] = data[[i, 2]]/20], 
   data[[i, 2]] = data[[i, 2]]], {i, 1, Length@data}];

N@data
```

> {{583., 614.}, {518., 744.}, {731., 1.83}, {783., 1.4825}, {693., 
>     7.42}, {658., 6.01}, {552., 741.}, {741., 1.4225}, {522., 
>     524.}, {705., 1.3325}}